# Best and most efficient way to populate different type of data

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have two `UICollectionView's` and I am passing a unique type of data (Cats, Dogs) to the same `UIViewController`. Both types have unique properties like imageUrl, gender, age and etc. What would be the best way to populate this data to according Text Views?

```
fileprivate var isDog = false

var detailsData: Any? {
    didSet {
        if detailsData is Dog {
            isDog = true
        } else if detailsData is Cat {
            isDog = false
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    isDog ? fillDogInfo(detailsData: detailsData as! Dog) : fillCatInfo(detailsData: detailsData as! Cat)
}

fileprivate func fillDogInfo(detailsData: Dog) {
    contactButtonOutlet.isHidden = false

    // Short Info
    if let name = detailsData.name {
        shortInfoMutableAttributedString.append("\(name)\n".customAttributedString(font: Font.header, textColor: UIColor.darkGray))
    }

    if let age = detailsData.age {
        shortInfoMutableAttributedString.append("\(age)\n".customAttributedString(font: Font.header, textColor: UIColor.darkGray))
    }

    shortInfoTextView.attributedText = shortInfoMutableAttributedString
}

fileprivate func fillCatInfo(detailsData: Car) {
    contactButtonOutlet.isHidden = true

    if let name = detailsData.name {
        shortInfoMutableAttributedString.append("\(name)\n".customAttributedString(font: Font.header, textColor: UIColor.darkGray))
    }

    if let gender = detailsData.gender {
        shortInfoMutableAttributedString.append("\(gender)\n".customAttributedString(font: Font.header, textColor: UIColor.darkGray))
    }

    shortInfoTextView.attributedText = shortInfoMutableAttributedString
}
```

Is there any other way to populate this data with less code?

Answer (score 0):

A classic case of Polymorphism, you should create a protocol and have the Dog and Cat classes implement it. Then you can just call the functions on this protocol instance.

Below is a simplified example. In this example, it does not make sense to make the distinction, since both `Cat` and `Dog` are the same class in terms of properties. This would become interesting if you want to make  a distinction, like for example add a `bark()` function to only the `Dog` class

```
protocol Pet{
    var name: String { get set}
    func infoString() -> String
}

class Dog: Pet{
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    func infoString() -> String {
        return "Dog \(name) has age \(age)"
    }
}

class Cat: Pet{
    var name: String
    var gender: String

    init(name: String, gender: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
    }

    func infoString() -> String {
        return "Cat \(name) has gender \(gender)"
    }
}


fileprivate func fillPetInfo(pet: Pet){
   textView.text = pet.infoString()
}

let dog = Dog(name: "Ruffer", age: 8)
fillPetInfo(pet: dog)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but they are not the same in terms of properties. One has gender and the other doesn't. One has age and the other doesn't.

Comment: The problem is "let dog = Dog(name: "Ruffer", age: 8)" that VC does not know if the data type is Dog or Cat. How can we know the data type before using it?

Comment: @Mamedoff That is the beauty of this, VC does not need to know the type, it should only use the type Pet the `let dog = ..` is just example usage. The specific implementations for Cat and Dog contain the logic for their specific types. You should read into Polymorphism for Object Oriented Programming

Comment: No you don't because the Pet protocol defines a function that returns the information. The VC only needs to call this function to get the data. e.g. `shortInfoTextView.attributedText = pet.getAttributedData()` or something like that. Next, both Dog and Cat will return different Strings, but VC does not need to know this implementation

Comment: Thank you for your help. What do you think about this code snippet? Am I doing it right? How can I improve it? https://pastebin.com/CQ74be86

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192727/discussion-between-tmkvu-and-mamedoff).